# Can I run SPARQL queries against a Wikidata dump locally?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

**TL;DR:** Is there a way I can download and install the data and software used for Wikidata's SPARQL endpoint query.wikidata.org locally? The reason I need this is that I have queries to run which often run into timeouts.

In another SO question, I have read that the software is Blazegraph.

**Long version:**

I'm using the SPARQL query service https://query.wikidata.org to run quite heavy queries against it. For example, the following query retrieves a list of all chemical compounds (instances of Q11173 or its subclasses):

```
SELECT ?item ?boiling_point ?melting_point ?decomp_point ?mass ?smiles
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?chemFormula; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?chemFormulae)
  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?chemStructure; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?chemStructures)
  WHERE {
    ?item wd:P31/wdt:P279*|wdt:P279* wd:Q11173.

    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P2102 ?boiling_point. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P2101 ?melting_point. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P2107 ?decomp_point. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P2067 ?mass. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P274 ?chemFormula. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P117 ?chemStructure. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P233 ?smiles. }
  }
  GROUP BY ?item ?boiling_point ?melting_point ?decomp_point ?mass ?smiles
```

[Here's a direct link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fboiling_point%20%3Fmelting_point%20%3Fdecomp_point%20%3Fmass%20%3Fsmiles%0A%20%20%20%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FchemFormula%3B%20SEPARATOR%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3FchemFormulae%29%0A%20%20%20%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FchemStructure%3B%20SEPARATOR%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3FchemStructures%29%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wd%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%7Cwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ11173.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2102%20%3Fboiling_point.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2101%20%3Fmelting_point.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2107%20%3Fdecomp_point.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2067%20%3Fmass.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP274%20%3FchemFormula.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP117%20%3FchemStructure.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP233%20%3Fsmiles.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3Fboiling_point%20%3Fmelting_point%20%3Fdecomp_point%20%3Fmass%20%3Fsmiles%0A).

Since there are over a million instances, this query is hitting the timeout of one minute, and I don't see a possibility to optimize the query, because even without the properties, and with a `LIMIT` of 10 entries, the query runs into the timeout:

```
SELECT ?item
  WHERE {
    ?item wd:P31/wdt:P279*|wdt:P279* wd:Q11173.
  }
```

[Direct link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wd%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%7Cwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ11173.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D).

I could query the subclasses individually by writing divide-and-conquer scripts, but before I do that, I wanted to check for a simpler possibility:

Comment: didn't you ask before how to load Wikidata dump and how long it takes? Download Blazegraph, download the wikidata dump, and load it. Takes a few days on a powerful server

Comment: Yes, sorry for asking again. The original question was deleted because someone serial-downvoted all my posts, and the anti-serial-voting bot corrected only half of those downvotes.

Comment: ok, I see. But the answers should be the same :D you can setup the Blazegraph and load Wikidata dump. But as said last time, it takes ~4 days on a good server iirc.